# JS Canvas Collision-Detection using getImageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors, collision, getimagedata

As a very inexperienced programmer, I'm trying to code a game that detects when the player collides with certain colors on the canvas. I have a black square with coordinates "player.x" and "player.y" and dimensions 50x50 that moves around when you press the arrow keys. I also have a stationary red (255,0,0) square elsewhere on the canvas.

The function below is supposed to grab a slightly larger square around the "player" square and find out if there's any red in it. If there is, it will send up an alert. The problem is, this doesn't seem to be working.

```
function collideTest(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var whatColor = c.getImageData(player.x - 5, player.y - 5,60,60);

    for (var i = 0; i < 3600; i++) {
        if (whatColor.data[i] == 255) {
            alert("red");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm semi-aware that this is not the most efficient way to detect red pixels, but I wanted to simplify the code before posting it here. Is there something obviously wrong with the function?

The problem could lie in the way the function is called. It gets called at the end of another function that detects user-input and changes the coordinates of the "player" square. THAT function gets called right before everything is drawn on the canvas.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each single pixel on the canvas, the whatColor.data array holds 4 sequential pieces of color information: red,green,blue,alpha(opacity).  So the whatColor.data looks like this for each pixel:

whatColor.data[i] is the red component of the color.

whatColor.data[i+1] is the green component of the color.

whatColor.data[i+2] is the blue component of the color.

whatColor.data[i+3] is the alpha(opacity) component of the color.

So your iteration would look like this (4 indexes per pixel):

```
 for(var i = 0, n = whatColor.data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      var red = whatColor.data[i];
      var green = whatColor.data[i + 1];
      var blue = whatColor.data[i + 2];
      var alpha = whatColor.data[i + 3];
      if(red==255){ ... it's a hit, do your thing! ... }
 }
```

See here for a mini-tutorial on the imageData.data array: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/

By the way, you might look at one of the canvas libraries that simplify game making with canvas.  Here are just a few: easelJs, KineticJs, FabricJs, and more!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I suspected, though, the contents of the function itself don't seem to be the problem. Even when I do what you've written there, I get no response upon hitting red. Could it be a matter of how the function is called?

Comment: As long as collideTest() gets called after the canvas has been fully rendered, then collideTest() is the right place to do hit-testing.  Although I don't know about your program logic, if you know the coordinates+sizes both the black box and the red box, you can do hit testing by analyzing their two bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var whatColor = c.getImageData(player.x - 5, player.y - 5,60,60);
```

`player.x` and `player.y` must not be decimal, make sure they are rounded or getImageData will be angry and not play nice.